# Choosing different environments on yo angular fullstack projects from grunt?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, angular-fullstack, yo

In the scaffold generated project using yo angular fullstack I normally launch the app with grunt using grunt (I am not an expert on it).

Example

```
grunt 

grunt serve
```

and so on.

As far as I know I have three different environments (Development, Test, Production). Every time I need to change I have to go to the main file changing the correct line (default is Development).

How can choose one of them from terminal? I am completely sure there has to be way to do that from grunt...

I can imagine it has to be something like

```
grunt serve --env:prod

grunt serve --test

grunt serve development
```

I have tried all of them but nothing, I have been spending some time trying to figure it out this from the Gruntfile but I cannot find neither googling.

Does anyone know how to do that? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can start your app like this `NODE_ENV=production grunt` and the environment variable is only production in this execution. If you want to set the environment variable you can do

```
> export NODE_ENV=production
> grunt
```

And your environment variable will remain in production until you change it for another environment.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. In fact, it is the best thing I can see to solve it!

Comment: I have just found it may be the answer grunt serve:dist..although I need someone to confirm. I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Look at `serve` task. There are different targets. You can set target by appending colon and target name.

**Development**

```
grunt serve
```

**Distribution (production)**

```
grunt serve:dist
```

**Debug**

```
grunt serve:debug
```

By setting target, Grunt will run different tasks.

`serve` task

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
  if (target === 'dist') {
    return grunt.task.run(['build', 'env:all', 'env:prod', 'express:prod', 'wait', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
  }

  if (target === 'debug') {
    return grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'env:all',<% if(filters.stylus) { %>
      'injector:stylus', <% } %><% if(filters.less) { %>
      'injector:less', <% } %><% if(filters.sass) { %>
      'injector:sass', <% } %>
      'concurrent:server',
      'injector',
      'wiredep',
      'autoprefixer',
      'concurrent:debug'
    ]);
  }

  grunt.task.run([
    'clean:server',
    'env:all',<% if(filters.stylus) { %>
    'injector:stylus', <% } %><% if(filters.less) { %>
    'injector:less', <% } %><% if(filters.sass) { %>
    'injector:sass', <% } %>
    'concurrent:server',
    'injector',
    'wiredep',
    'autoprefixer',
    'express:dev',
    'wait',
    'open',
    'watch'
  ]);
});
```